# Address a single row of a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way in c# to address a single row of a 2-dimensional array?

I want to be able to pass one-dimension of a 2 dimensional array as a parameter and sometimes I want to pass the whole 2-dimentional array.

Comment: You can use jagged arrays to do this.

Comment: Could you provide any examples please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jagged arrays.

Example based on the code in [Jagged Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx):

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][];

jaggedArray[0] = new int[5];
jaggedArray[1] = new int[4];
jaggedArray[2] = new int[2];

// To pass the whole thing, use jaggedArray
// To pass one of the inner arrays, use jaggedArray[index]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How about the performance compared to 2 dimentiosnal array?

Comment: @user1199526 - That will be entirely dependent on usage. You need to test performance against your own usage.

Comment: Final question, what if i use the structs to do the same? Is there any advantage of using jagged arrays compared to structs

Comment: Type safety and expressiveness of structs would be a benefit. As for performance - measure, measure and measure.